# Locating source code of the PureOS installer

Tags: debian-installer, source, source-code, pureos

I have been playing with PureOS installation options (the ultimate goal is to install it dual boot with MacOS on a MacBook Air, but this is out of the scope of this question).

What I would like to see is how this "Boot loader location: Boot Partition (/boot)" option actually works behind the scenes (in particular, how it makes the Mac's bootloader know where the `/boot` partition is, by "blessing"?):

[image]

I thought that digging through the source code of that installer should shed some light on what it does. I therefore went to see what is under the "[Source Code](http://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/)" link on their website, but it looks like a packages repo rather than source code:

[image]

So, the question is: where is the source code of the PureOS bootloader installer? Am I just missing something obvious, or is it not actually available?

Comment: It seems there's more code there : https://tracker.pureos.net/diffusion/
Otherwise I would say as the Mac probably uses UEFI, so the installer is probably updating the EFI boot loader as you would on a regular PC, by adding an entry using efibootmgr maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link provided does indeed point to a package repository, but that package repository also includes all the source code for the packages. All the tarballs contain source code: in the example you show, the various `.orig.tar.xz` files contain the upstream source, and the `.debian.tar.xz` files contain the distribution-specific patches applied to them.

PureOS seems to use [the Calamares installer framework](https://calamares.io/about/); this is where the “Boot loader location” selection lives. You’ll find the source code for the PureOS version in [the relevant repository](https://source.puri.sm/pureos/core/calamares), and all the PureOS core source code [just above](https://source.puri.sm/pureos/core).